# Laravel : Query to get a single column in response from a JSON column in mysql 5.7

Tags: php, mysql, json, laravel

I have a mysql database (5.7.1) with a table "inventory" containing 2 columns :

- id {String}
- content {json}

The content column contains a json with severals keys:

```
{
     "id" : "myId",
     "arrayOfEl" : [
        {id : "1", always : true},
        {id : "1", always : true}
     ]
}
```

I try to make a query in laravel to get only the arrayOfEl keys from the content column of the specified id:

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('id', "myId")->get(????);
```

How don't know where specify in the query to get only the sub-column arrayOfEl in response ?

Answer (score 0):

Unless your table is `json` type, you might need to fetch the whole rows then try to filter them. Make sure you define attribute casting on the model, example here using collection

```
protected $casts = [
    'arrayOfEl' => 'collection',
];
```

And then try to find match

```
$myId = 'myId'; // id of content
$inventory = Inventory::all()->filter(function ($item) use ($myId) {
   return is_object($item->content) && $item->content->id == $myId;
})->first();
```

Or if you have `json` type column. You can simply filter it based on `->` notation.

```
->where('content->id', 'myId')
```

Comment: Yes, my column has the json type, so i will use the '->' syntax. But how can i do to return only the arrayOfEl key with this method ?

Comment: Just like a normal query `->where('content->id', 'myId')->get(['arrayOfEl'])->get('arrayOfEl')` or `pluck('arrayOfel)` or `->where('content->id', 'myId')->get(['arrayOfEl'])->map->get('arrayOfEl')` That's all.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pluck` to get only the columns you need.

```
$inventory = Inventory::where('id', 'myId')->pluck('arrayOfEl');
```